# Downloading web page in the background with wxHtmlWindow

Tags: http, asynchronous, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets to download the contents of a website into a wxHtmlWindow control. This works flawlessly, except for one thing. The entire gui seems to freeze while the data is being downloaded, which is highly problematic for my application. In most other wxWidgets class methods, events continue to be processed automagicly for you even if the call in question is said to be blocking. This does not appear to be the case here, and I am wondering how I might tell wxWidgets to download the page in the background? I am currently using the LoadPage method.

I guess I could use a second thread, but with the restrictions that wxWidgets imposes on changing the state of any window through any thread other than the main one makes me hesitate to dive into this. Is there a better way? The raw http class, for instance, does not block the window while it's downloading so I don't understand why wxHtmlWindow, which surely must be using the raw http class internally, does not have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately wxHtmlWindow uses synchronous sockets to fetch contents of a URL. Call hiearchy goes like this:  wxHtmlWindow -> wxHtmlParser -> wxFileSystem -> wxURI -> wxHTTP -> wxHTTP::GetInputStream .  The GetInputStream method will use the open a socket in blocking mode.

You will need to use a separate thread to fetch the contents of a website.

Comment: This is very unfortunate, but my own investigation seems to lead to the exact same conclusion that you outline. Thanks for taking the time to clear this up!